syntax error, unexpected token "for", expecting "]" ,what is syntax error here?
php syntax error
i want here make loop and put result from request in array
class InsertimgController extends Controller
{

    public function insertimg(Request $request){
            $y= count($request->all())-1;
            $x = [
                for($z=1; $z<=$y; $z++){
                    $request[$z];
                }];
                return [array_sum($x) , $y];
    }
}


$x=[]; for($z=1; $z<=$y; $z++) $x[] = $request[$z];

You can't loop inside an array declaration

What made you think this is valid PHP code?

This looks like an attempt to translate "list comprehension" syntax from Python, but PHP has no such syntax. If some tutorial or tool told you this is how to write it, probably best not to trust anything else that tutorial or tool tells you.

class InsertimgController extends Controller
{
    public function insertimg(Request $request){
        $y= count($request->all())-1;
            
        for($z=1; $z<=$y; $z++){
            $x[] = $request[$z];
        }
        return [array_sum($x) , $y];
    }
}

